# How to log data into a table in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have numericInput and tableOutput widgets. At the moment any number that is typed in the box is printed in the table on the same row. What I would like to do is print every new entry on a new row so that the table automatically expands (gets taller) and logs all entries. I don’t necessarily need to use the table from the shiny package. Would the solution be different for a table from the DT or Formattable packages for example? The reprex is:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput(inputId = "num", label = h3("Enter value:"), value = "")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderTable({
        paste("Value is:", input$num, sep = "\n")
    },
    bordered = TRUE)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you expecting to "store" past entries and then augment them? I think you need to solve this *outside* of `shiny` before you put things into it. Hint: `rbind`, `dplyr::add_row`, or some other mechanism to add to a (real) `data.frame` that is presented in your table output. When you figure that out, a good practice in `shiny` is to separate *data* into its own reactive elements, and then use those elements in other blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to solve how to add to a `data.frame`. I'll preface this up-front that growing objects (`data.frame`s) in R is inefficient memory-wise: each time you add one row, the entire frame is copied in memory. For a moment in time (until R does some memory management and garbage collection), there are two complete copies of the frame in memory, whether it has 2 rows or 20 million rows. For small numbers this is fine, but it scales poorly. I'm suggesting this solution *despite* this, since I believe thstrong textat your use will be on a small scale and likely won't be a problem. However, if you plan to apply this to something else a bit larger, please keep this in mind; not only is it bad on memory, but each copy (with lots of rows) will be slower than the last.

There are two ways to extend a `data.frame` by one or more rows: `rbind` (which has a `data.frame` S3 method) or just rebuilding it. The two `mylog` functions below demonstrate both of these: given the previous data (or `NULL` for the first time) and an entry, it returns an augmented frame.

```r
mylog1 <- function(dat, entry) {
  if (is.null(dat)) dat <- data.frame(timestamp = character(0), entry = integer(0))
  rbind.data.frame(dat, data.frame(
    timestamp = rep(format(Sys.time(), format = "%H:%M:%S"), length(entry)),
    entry = entry,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
mylog2 <- function(dat, entry) {
  if (is.null(dat)) dat <- data.frame(timestamp = character(0), entry = integer(0))
  data.frame(
    timestamp = c(dat$timestamp, rep(format(Sys.time(), format = "%H:%M:%S"), length(entry))),
    entry = c(dat$entry, entry),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}

library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        numericInput(inputId = "num", label = h3("Enter value:"), value = "")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("table")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    mydata <- reactiveVal( mylog1(NULL, integer(0)) )
    num_debounced <- debounce(reactive(input$num), 3000)
    observeEvent(num_debounced(), {
      req(input$num)
      dat <- mylog1(mydata(), num_debounced())
      mydata(dat)
    })
    output$table <- renderTable({
      req(mydata())
    },
    bordered = TRUE)
  }
)
```

[image: sample shiny app]

Notes:

1. Whenever I have a "log" or similar table that should always be the same structure (number and names of columns), I find it best to define it *in one place*, typically a helper function. This is absolutely not required, but if/when you ever change the format of the table and miss one place that you insert into it, you'll understand what I mean. When its format is augmented in multiple places, it is easy to miss one when formatting it. In my case, the only place to change the layout of the table is within the function itself.
2. The `num` entry field might be too "responsive" in that as soon as somebody *slows* typing, its value is read and used. I find this can be problematic in user interfaces, so I added `shiny::debounce`: the input field is not considered usable until the user has stopped typing in the field for some time (3 seconds here). I think 3 seconds is entirely too long for this demo, but I think it gets the point across. If you want 1 second, change 3000 to 1000. If you want to remove it, change all `num_debounced()` to `input$num` and remove the `debounce` line of code.
3. It is almost always (actually, I cannot think of a viable exception) to separate data reactives from rendering reactives. That is, I think you should not be attempting to augment data within something like `renderTable`. It is better to formulate the data elsewhere (in its own reactive block) and then use that table within the rendering function. This is for several reasons, the leading (for me) is that I usually want to use that data in multiple places, whether for rendering or just reference (this reason is not apparent in this app, but I do it anyway). Another reason is that is simplifies the rendering reactive lock a little.
4. I use `req(...)` to `req`uire that values be ["truthy"](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html) (not `NULL`, etc). Without it, for instance, the log table will start with a row that has an empty entry, because it fired on the first shot. Also, if the user enters something (adding a row) then deletes the entry, this will prevent an empty row being added. To see how that works, remove `req(input$num)` then add an entry, then empty the input field.